# 403 Error : Upload to google cloud storage bucket from google compute engine using python

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

I am trying to upload a file to google cloud storage from a python script on google compute engine and get error below. Script runs fine as google cloud function. What right way to permission bucket ?

```
Adding new file
403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/XXX/o?uploadType=multipart: ('Request failed with status code', 403, 'Expected on
e of', <HTTPStatus.OK: 200>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look to this [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts)

You can customize your service account per user this one per default.

However, some libraries perform API call like bucket.list or bucket.get and you have to authorize in addition of storage Object read/write role, the storage admin role. Or create a custom role.